# asp:DataGrid not displaying data on Delegate callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, datatable

When I click the Shutdown button, it does send a message and I get the response too which I can verify in DataTable. But DataGrid is not getting populated. I check the Rows property of DataGrid, it has rows, however the page doesn't display the results.

Here is my code:

BasicControls.aspx page

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <%-- asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateTimer" EventName="Tick" />--%>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="cmdResultsgrdView">
            <asp:GridView ID="grdMessage" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ListenerTimer" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
```

.aspx.cs file

```
{
    private static Action<List<IMessage>> callBackCommandResponse = null;
    //ctor
    public BasicControls()
    {
        callBackCommandResponse = CommandResponse;
    }
    //Callback Method
    public void CommandResponse(List<IMessage> Message)
    {
        //Based on MsgType we will filter and display the response.
        if (null != Message)
        {
            //2. Call GetMessage to filter and process message and return DataTable
            resultsDataTable = GetMessages(Message);
            //3. Populate the Grid binding to DataTable
            grdMessage.DataSource = resultsDataTable;
            grdMessage.DataBind();
        }
    }
    //receiver constructor in which we are passing callback to be populated. 
    private ReceivePM receiver = new ReceivePM(callBackCommandResponse);

    //On clicking the code sends Shutdown Command to message queue.
    protected void btnShutdown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SenderInformation cmdSender = new SenderInformation();
        cmdSender.SendShutdownCommand();
    }
}
```

Comment: Gridview is inside UpdatePanel1, and UpdateMode is "Conditional", then you will need to call Update() method manually in code behind. Try calling "UpdatePanel1.Update()" method after DataBind() event.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling "UpdatePanel1.Update()" method after DataBind() event.

```
grdMessage.DataSource = resultsDataTable;
grdMessage.DataBind();
UpdatePanel1.Update();
```

Comment: It should have worked if you are able to see the rows in the datasource.
Did you try changing UpdateMode to "Always", which is default mode?

Comment: I tested with both. what is happening is that when i click the button, Postback happens and it sends out the commands. I am getting the data via callback, but the DataGrid is already rendered. I have textbox also within the update Panel, even that is not getting rendered

Comment: Oops.. Didn't think of it. you will have to implement ICallBackEventHandler. For more information, please check out this article [Binding GridView using CallBack](http://dotnetmashala.blogspot.ca/2010/11/binding-gridview-using-callback.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. 
But I guess mine was a different scenario where the application was interacting with 
Queue.
So, I did not use ICallBackEventHandler, I implemented my own callback and started the Queue listener method as a separate task instead of inside a timer.
Following piece of code is required in case you have your own callbacks
                if (resultsDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    grdMessage.DataSource = resultsDataTable;
                    grdMessage.DataBind();
                    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                    grdMessage.RenderControl(hw);

```
            }
```